# DataGridViewComboBox null values

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, null, dbnull

I have a Windows forms DataGridView with a combobox column.  The combo box column is bound to a data source that is populated from a Linq to Entities query.  I would like users to be able to select "Nothing" in the combo box (assign a value of NULL to the underlying data source).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I spent days trying to figure out a nice re-useable 'nullable combobox' in WPF by simply modifying the style or control template of a regular combobox... but never found a great solution. Tried everything from composite collections, inserting a dummy value in codebehind... every suggested method I found had something bad about it that I couldn't figure out a good work-around. I hope somebody posts a new good solution here... but honestly... I'm guessing creating your own user-control from scratch that handles all of the stuff is going to be your best bet (then use editing element style)

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView supports the Ctrl+0 keystroke to enter a null value into a cell, so you can use that to clear out a combo box's value and set it back to null.